# Is there a way to identify if an array matches with each set in the 2d array after looping through a 2d array for each element in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, tic-tac-toe

I'm creating a tictactoe game and I'm trying to compare each set array within the winPattern 2d array to the placePieces array.

I've created loops to iterate through the winPattern 2d array for each placePieces array but because it doesn't recognize each array as a set and simply iterates through individual values, it doesn't work as intended.

```
const winPattern = [
        //horizontal
        [0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8],

        //vertical
        [0, 3, 6],
        [1, 4, 7],
        [2, 5, 8],

        //diagonal
        [0, 4, 8],
        [2, 4, 6]
  ];
//positions that o or x would be in tictactoe
const placePieces = [0, 1, 2, 4, 8];
let count = 0;

nextPiece:
for (let i = 0; i < placePieces.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < winPattern.length; j++) {
        for (let n = 0; n < winPattern[0].length; n++) {
            if (placePieces[i] === winPattern[j][n]) {
                //Prints out the matches and mismatches
                console.log(`It matches: Piece: ${placePieces[i]} //\\ Pattern: ${winPattern[j][n]}`);

                continue nextPiece;
            } else {
                console.log(`It doesn't match: Piece: ${placePieces[i]} //\\Pattern: ${winPattern[j][n]}`);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm expecting the placePieces array to compare values with each SET of arrays in the winPattern 2d array.

Comment: **Hint:** you can use array functions to check that in one line like so: `let winCheck = winPattern.some(pat => pat.every(pos => placePieces.includes(pos)));` which just checks if there is a pattern `pat` in `winPatterns` that has all its elements included in `placePieces`. Less headaches!

Answer (score 1):

This code should work to see if the users current array matches anything in the answers array -

```
    var winPattern = [
        //horizontal
        [0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8],

        //vertical
        [0, 3, 6],
        [1, 4, 7],
        [2, 5, 8],

        //diagonal
        [0, 4, 8],
        [2, 4, 6]
  ];
//positions that o or x would be in tictactoe
var placePieces = [0, 1, 2, 4, 8, ];
var count = 0;

function arraysEqual(a, b) {
  if (a === b) return true;
  if (a == null || b == null) return false;
  if (a.length != b.length) return false;


  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    if (a[i] !== b[i]) return false;
  }
  return true;
}


function checkMatch(arr){
  for(var i = 0; i < winPattern.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < arr.length - 2; j++){
      for(var k = j + 1; k < arr.length - 1; k++){
        for(var l = k + 1; l < arr.length; l++){
          var possibleAnswer = [arr[j], arr[k], arr[l]];
          if(arraysEqual(possibleAnswer, winPattern[i])) return true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

This is assuming placePieces is sorted because it seemed like it was in your example.  Hope this helps!